# For wx.Python How come style=wx.NO_BORDER makes classes contained within it see no width or height

Tags: python-3.x

So I have the borrowed code below.  It works as expected
until I add "style=wx.NO_BORDER)" to wx.Frame.**init** .

Why do the panels lose height and width?

To see what it produces, eliminate the NO_BORDER style and run.  Then put it back in and see the panels shrink

```
    import wx

########################################################################
class RandomPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, color):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)



########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        topSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        hSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(topSplitter)

        panelOne = RandomPanel(hSplitter, "blue")
        panelTwo = RandomPanel(hSplitter, "red")
        hSplitter.SplitVertically(panelOne, panelTwo)
        hSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.7)

        panelThree = RandomPanel(topSplitter, "green")
        topSplitter.SplitHorizontally(hSplitter, panelThree)
        topSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(topSplitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Nested Splitters",
                  size=(800,600), style=wx.NO_BORDER)
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer elsewhere

In the Frame constructor, I added

```
   self.Layout()
```

right before

```
   self.Show()
```

This made the code work as expected